# Possible bug in the help page?

Tags: bug, status-completed, obsolete, documentation, api-v1

There are some weird dot things in this help page:

[api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help/method?method=users/{id}/badges](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/users/1/badges?help)

{Dead link to missing image: `http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/stackbug.png`}

What's up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're called bullets and there's simply some missing text.

- Make a list
- Add some items
- ???
- Profit

<sup><sub>*It never gets old.*</sub></sup>

Comment: Meh. Vote up and accept. Why not?

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed.